# fadeIn/fadeOut <div> on radio and/or select option being selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot find a perfect solution for this. 
Is there a simple way to fadeIn the `".filter_on"` div, if I click on a select option and/or radio button?

And by default, get this div to fade out again afterwards?

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyd7a2s8/)

```
<div class="filter">
Filter <span class="filter_on">active</span>
</div>

<form>
    <p>Vehicle?</p>
     <select name="vehicle" size="2">
        <option>Bike</option>
        <option>Car</option>
     </select>
</form>

<form>
    <p>City?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="all" name="city" value="All" checked>
        <label for="all"> All</label></input>
        <input type="radio" id="ny" name="city" value="New York">
        <label for="ny"> New York</label></input>
        <input type="radio" id="mh" name="city" value="Manhattan">
        <label for="mh"> Manhattan</label></input>
</form>
```

Comment: By fadeIn, do you mean just turning it visible or showing it like a growl? (Take a look at the jQuery Plugin BlockUI - http://malsup.com/jquery/block/ -to get what I mean)

Comment: Do you want to fade the `.filter` div when radio button selected ? or when do a selection ?

Comment: Tushar has a good demo, but the fade out doesn´t work ;(

Comment: @Pepe As mentioned, I dont think `fadeOut` is ever needed

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ckvdxy1L/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo -> http://jsfiddle.net/vyd7a2s8/4/

```
var defaultRadio = $(':radio:checked');
var defaultVehicle = $('[name=vehicle] option:selected');
$('[name=vehicle],[name=city]').on('change', function (e) {
    var currentRadio = $(':radio:checked');
    var currentVehicle = $('[name=vehicle] option:selected');

    if (currentRadio[0].isEqualNode(defaultRadio[0]) && currentVehicle[0].isEqualNode(defaultVehicle[0])) {
        $('.filter_on').fadeOut(500);
    } else {
        $('.filter_on').fadeIn(500);
    }
});
```

***Explanation*** - This will store the default selected values outside the function and uses them inside the click event to check the newly selected values.

Comment: Sry, maybe my fail, but I dont want that the div automatically fades out, it should fade out if I set the radio buttons back to default or deselect the select.

Comment: So, I have tested all great examples on this page here and your example is the best one for me (because I also want to work with more then one select box) - big thx!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `fadeOut` since you cannot unselect from drop-down or cannot uncheck the radio button.

```
$('select, :radio').on('change', function() {
    if ($('select option:selected').length === 0 && $(':radio:checked').val() === 'All') {
        $('.filter_on').fadeOut();
    } else {
        $('.filter_on').fadeIn();
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

`trigger` will execute this function automatically. Will `fadeIn` on the page load.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vyd7a2s8/1/

Comment: Thats really close what I was looking for, BUT I also want that the div fades out if nothing is selected or the radio buttons are default.

Comment: First, thx for support! Maybe I am wrong, but I dont think that this works like the way I need it. For example, if I select "New York" the div fades in *perfect!* but if I select "All" (thats the default) the div dont fade out ;(.

Comment: "Arun P" has written the answer I was looking for - but thx for support!